# How to group one to many relationships with join in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and trying to return data from multiple tables using a join.

I'm using 3 models / tables, Customer, Business and Website which are related as follows:

In Customer.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
  public function businesses()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Business');
  }
}
```

In Business.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
  public function customer() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
  }

  public function websites()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Website');
  }
}
```

And in Website.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Website extends Model
{  
  public function business() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
  }
}
```

So a `Customer` can have many `Businesses` which can have many `Websites`.
Now I'm trying to use a join statement to return a list of the customers and their related business and website information. I'm using the following code to return this information:

```
$customers = \DB::table('customers')
                ->join('businesses', 'customers.id', '=', 'businesses.customer_id')
                ->join('websites', 'businesses.id', '=', 'websites.business_id')
                ->select('customers.x', 'businesses.y', 'websites.z')
                ->get();
```

And I'd like the data to be return in an array of associative customer arrays with the business and websites data nested in the associative array like so:

```
[
  0 => {
    $customer1Data,
    $customer1BusinessData,
    $customer1WebsiteData
  }
  1 => {
   $customer2Data,
   $customer2BusinessData,
   $customer2WebsiteData
  }
  ...
]
```

This works fine if a customer has one business which has one website but suppose `$customer1` has two businesses, then the above join returns something in this format:

```
[
  0 => {
    $customer1Data,
    $customer1BusinessData1,
    $customer1WebsiteData
  }
  1 => {
   $customer1Data,
   $customer1BusinessData2,
   $customer1WebsiteData
  }
  ...
]
```

Is there a way I can modify the join statement to return that scenario in this format:

```
[
  0 => {
    $customer1Data,
    businesses => {
      $customer1BusinessData1,
      $customer1BusinessData2
    }
    ...
  }
]
```

Is there a way I can achieve this with join statements? Or should I be approaching this in a different way? Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: you have not completely utilized the eloquent. you can just use ` $customer = Customer::with('business', 'business.websites')->all() ` This would load all the customers, with their business and its websites. so you can simply use ` $customer->business ` to get all the business and a nested loop to get the websites of businesses.

Answer (score 1):

Before I dive into explaining eloquent model relations, read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent. This will clear things up.

In a model relation you can specify what the database field names are that link those two tables together. This even works with pivot tables. For the basic documentation read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships.

For example in the customer model:

```
public function businesses() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Business::class, 'id', 'customer_id');
}

public function websites()
{
    //Argument order: final class, pivot class, pivot foreign key, foreign key final model, primary key start model (customer)
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Website::class, Business::class, 'customer_id', 'id', id);
}
```

If this last part was a bit hard to understand, read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

And for the Business model:

```
public function website()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Website::class, 'id', 'business_id');
}
```

And now you can retrieve data by using eloquent.

```
//This will retrieve all customers with all of their website information.
Customer::with('websites')->get();

//This will retrieve all customers with their business information.
Customer::with('businesses')->get();

//This will retrieve all customers with business and website information
//Retrieves: [ 
//    customer: [ 
//        customerDetails: [] 
//        businesses: [ b1, b2], 
//        websites: [w1, w2]
//    ]
//]
Customer::with('businesses', 'websites')->get();

//This will retrieve all customers with business information and the website information for each business
//Retrieves: [ 
//    customer: [ 
//        customerDetails: [] 
//        businesses: [ 
//            b1: [ websites: [w1] ],
//            b2: [ websites: [w2] ]
//        ], 
//    ]
//]
Customer::with('businesses.websites')->get();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: If you place a key value array within the ->get(), then you can specify the columns you want to retrieve. Don't forget the table names!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by @Rooshan Akthar, you can do one the following using eloquent because of the relationships you have created:

```
// Loading with relationships (i.e single query)
Customer::with('businesses.websites');

// Lazy loading (i.e. multiple queries)
Customer::find($id)->load('businesses.websites');
```

You can also just go `$customer->businesses->websites;` without having called either of the above and laravel will get those relationships for you.