# How can group a laravel collection like MySQL GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-collection

I have a Laravel function that returns this resulting merged collection, from a more than two or three individual collections (different BD queries):

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3361
     all: [
       {#3359
         +"id": 3,
         +"name": "Jose Achecar",
         +"role": 1,
       },
       {#3344
         +"id": 1,
         +"name": "Oswaldo Graterol",
         +"role": 1,
       },
       {#3384
         +"id": 4,
         +"name": "Assaily",
         +"role": 2,
       },
       {#3372
         +"id": 3,
         +"name": "Jose Achecar",
         +"role": 2,
       },       
       {#3349
         +"id": 5,
         +"name": "Alejandro",
         +"role": 1,
       },
       {#3382
         +"id": 2,
         +"name": "Marcos Mendozas",
         +"role": 2,
       },
     ],
   }
```

As you can see, there is an element (the one with `id` 3) that has two roles and is displayed twice

There is a method or helper that can be used to group the collection and get something like this:

```
  Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3361
     all: [
       {#3359
         +"id": 3,
         +"name": "Jose Achecar",
         +"role": [1,2],
       },
       {#3344
         +"id": 1,
         +"name": "Oswaldo Graterol",
         +"role": [1],
       },
       {#3384
         +"id": 4,
         +"name": "Assaily",
         +"role": [2],
       },    
       {#3349
         +"id": 5,
         +"name": "Alejandro",
         +"role": [1],
       },
       {#3382
         +"id": 2,
         +"name": "Marcos Mendozas",
         +"role": [2],
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? Do you have a flat table with users details and roles, or two different tables, `users` and `roles`, with [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) relationship?

Comment: Hi thanks, I have 3 tables: users, roles, groups. A user can have more than one role in a group. The collection in this post is an example, really the collection has more fields, because I don't think I can use a function like group_concat when DB query.

Comment: By the way, I have no defined relationships between these tables.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at relationships, it helps simplifying queries. Can you please post your laravel eloquent query? (and yes, it is great that you reduce your code to minimum which helps understanding your problem :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You did not include any code, which makes it harder to answer.

Basically, there are two approaches for working with databases in Laravel:

1. DB facade
2. Eloquent Models

While [DB facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries) provides an interface for query building, Eloquent supplies objects (models) which represent tables.

From [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#introduction):

> Laravel includes Eloquent, an object-relational mapper (ORM) that
> makes it enjoyable to interact with your database. When using
> Eloquent, each database table has a corresponding "Model" that is used
> to interact with that table. In addition to retrieving records from
> the database table, Eloquent models allow you to insert, update, and
> delete records from the table as well.

Now, if you work with models, your friend is [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method. You have a lot of information, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275398/1039488) for example.
In few words - the idea is to perform one `SELECT` query, then iterate the result with [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function.

Otherwise, supposing that you do not work with models, you can achieve what you want with pure php code (please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41674465/1039488)).

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I'd do it like that:

```php
$coll = $coll->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
  if (!$carry->contains('id', $item->id)) {
    $newItem = clone $item;
    $newItem->role = [ $newItem->role ];
    $carry->push($newItem);
  } else {
    $carry->firstWhere('id', $item->id)->role[] = $item->role;
  }
  return $carry;
}, new Illuminate\Support\Collection());
```